# Pandas. How to create a new column with a little and simple function

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am very new at Pandas so I don´t know how to do this.

I have a Python scrip with Pandas to retrieve the data from an online .csv with covid data for the provinces in Spain. I want to create a new column to make a new var. These would be the (new deaths at day/100.000 population)
Its possible?

In the csv we have already the population data, so
The function would be : (population/1.000.000)*daily_deaths

This is my code, so I don´t know how start

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/montera34/escovid19data/master/data/output/covid19-provincias-spain_consolidated.csv")
df1  = pd.DataFrame(df1) #no index



Albacete = df1.loc[df1["province"] == "Albacete"]
Alicante = df1[df1['ine_code'] == 3][['date',"PCR","TestAc",'province',"new_cases","activos","hospitalized","intensive_care","deceased","cases_accumulated","recovered","cases_per_cienmil","intensive_care_per_1000000","deceassed_per_100000","hospitalized_per_100000","daily_deaths","deaths_last_week"]]
Almeria  = df1.loc[df1['ine_code'] == 3]
Alava    = df1.loc[df1['ine_code'] == 1]
Asturias = df1.loc[df1['ine_code'] == 33]
Avila    = df1.loc[df1['ine_code'] == 5]
Badajoz  = df1.loc[df1['ine_code'] == 6]
Baleares = df1.loc[df1['ine_code'] == 7]
Barcelona= df1.loc[df1['ine_code'] == 8]
Bizcaia  = df1.loc[df1['ine_code'] == 48]
Burgos   = df1.loc[df1['ine_code'] == 9]
Caceres  = df1.loc[df1['ine_code'] == 10]
Cadiz    = df1.loc[df1['ine_code'] == 11]
Cantabria= df1.loc[df1['ine_code'] == 39] 
Castellon= df1.loc[df1['ine_code'] == 12]
Ceuta    = df1.loc[df1['ine_code'] == 51]
Ciudad_R = df1.loc[df1['ine_code'] == 13]
Cordoba  = df1.loc[df1['ine_code'] == 14]
Cuenca   = df1.loc[df1['ine_code'] == 16]
Guipuzcoa= df1.loc[df1['ine_code'] == 20]
Girona   = df1.loc[df1['ine_code'] == 17] 
Madrid   = df1[df1['ine_code'] == 28][['date',"PCR","TestAc",'province',"new_cases","activos","hospitalized","intensive_care","deceased","cases_accumulated","recovered","cases_per_cienmil","intensive_care_per_1000000","deceassed_per_100000","hospitalized_per_100000","daily_deaths","deaths_last_week"]]





Columnas  = df1[['date','province',"new_cases","PCR","TestAc","activos","hospitalized","intensive_care","deceased","cases_accumulated","recovered","cases_per_cienmil","intensive_care_per_1000000","deceassed_per_100000","hospitalized_per_100000","daily_deaths","deaths_last_week"]] # erro DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed


with pd.ExcelWriter('spain provinces.xlsx') as writer:  
   

   #Select the provinces you want

   #Columnas.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Datos por provincias")
   #Albacete.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Albacete")
   #Alicante.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Alicante")
   #Alicante = df1[df1['ine_code'] == 3][['date','province',"new_cases","PCR","TestAc","activos","hospitalized","intensive_care","deceased","cases_accumulated","recovered","cases_per_cienmil","intensive_care_per_1000000","deceassed_per_100000","hospitalized_per_100000","daily_deaths","deaths_last_week"]]
   #Madrid   = df1[df1['ine_code'] == 28][['date',"PCR","TestAc",'province',"new_cases","activos","hospitalized","intensive_care","deceased","cases_accumulated","recovered","cases_per_cienmil","intensive_care_per_1000000","deceassed_per_100000","hospitalized_per_100000","daily_deaths","deaths_last_week"]]
   Murcia  = df1[df1['ine_code'] == 30][['date',"PCR","TestAc",'province',"new_cases","activos","hospitalized","intensive_care","deceased","cases_accumulated","recovered","cases_per_cienmil","intensive_care_per_1000000","deceassed_per_100000","hospitalized_per_100000","daily_deaths","deaths_last_week"]]
   Rioja   = df1[df1['ine_code'] == 26][['date',"PCR","TestAc",'province',"new_cases","activos","hospitalized","intensive_care","deceased","cases_accumulated","recovered","cases_per_cienmil","intensive_care_per_1000000","deceassed_per_100000","hospitalized_per_100000","daily_deaths","deaths_last_week"]]
   Albacete   = df1[df1['ine_code'] == 2][['date',"PCR","TestAc",'province',"new_cases","activos","hospitalized","intensive_care","deceased","cases_accumulated","recovered","cases_per_cienmil","intensive_care_per_1000000","deceassed_per_100000","hospitalized_per_100000","daily_deaths","deaths_last_week"]]
   Alicante   = df1[df1['ine_code'] == 3][['date',"PCR","TestAc",'province',"new_cases","activos","hospitalized","intensive_care","deceased","cases_accumulated","recovered","cases_per_cienmil","intensive_care_per_1000000","deceassed_per_100000","hospitalized_per_100000","daily_deaths","deaths_last_week","poblacion"]]
   Valencia  = df1[df1['ine_code'] == 46][['date',"PCR","TestAc",'province',"new_cases","activos","hospitalized","intensive_care","deceased","cases_accumulated","recovered","cases_per_cienmil","intensive_care_per_1000000","deceassed_per_100000","hospitalized_per_100000","daily_deaths","deaths_last_week"]]

   #Almeria.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Almería")
   #Alava.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Alava")
   #Asturias.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Asturias")
   #Avila.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Avila")
   #Badajoz.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Badajoz")
   #Baleares.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Baleares")
   #Barcelona.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Barcelona")
   #Bizcaia.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Bizcaia")
   #Burgos.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Burgos")
   #Caceres.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Caceres")
   #Cadiz.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Cadiz")
   #df[['col_name1', 'col_name2']]Cantabria.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Cantabria")
   #Castellon.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Castellon")
   #Ceuta.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Ceuta")
   #Ciudad_R.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Ciudad Real")
   #Cordoba.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Cordoba")
   #Cuenca.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Cuenca")
   #Guipuzcoa.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Guipuzcoa")
   #Girona.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Girona")

   #csv.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Dades Obertes")



   #df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="esCovid19data") #ALL OF DATA OF THE CSV

   Alicante.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Alicante")
   #Madrid.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Madrid")
   #Murcia.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Murcia")
   #Rioja.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Rioja")
   #Albacete.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Albacete")
   #Valencia.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Valencia")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't easily see all your DataFrame columns but try something like:

```
df1['percent_per_day'] = (df1['population']/1000000) * df1['daily_deaths']
```

Where:

`df1['percent_per_day']` is your new column

`df1['population']` and `df1['daily_deaths']` are whatever those columns are called in df1

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but based on the columns in the csv try this where 'poblacion' is population

```
df1['death_rate'] = (df1['poblacion']/1000000) *df1['daily_deaths']
```